# Postfix: "relay access denied" for all incoming mail?

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server

I'm attempting to setup a **small mail server** with **Postfix**, **Dovecot**, and **MySQL** (MariaDB) on Debian. I've also configured **SSL** with **Let's Encrypt**.

So far I haven't setup rDNS, DKIM, DMARC, SPF, etc. - which I will still attempt later -, but **sending e-mails** with the `mail` command already works great. They don't end up in spam or get rejected.

**Receiving mail** doesn't work! Here's the error message from */var/log/mail.log*:

```
Jan 13 09:27:39 [hostname] postfix/smtpd[1016]: connect from mx1.riseup.net[198.252.153.129]
Jan 13 09:27:40 [hostname] postfix/smtpd[1016]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx1.riseup.net[198.252.153.129]: 554 5.7.1 <info@[domain].net>: Relay access denied; from=<[user]@riseup.net> to=<info@[domain].net> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx1.riseup.net>
Jan 13 09:27:40 [hostname] postfix/smtpd[1016]: disconnect from mx1.riseup.net[198.252.153.129] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/8
```

*riseup.net* is the email provider that I sent the message from for testing purposes. I also tried Gmail with the same outcome.

I've setup **A/AAAA records** for *[hostname].[domain].net*, as well as a **MX record** also for *[hostname].[domain].net*.

My */etc/hosts* file looks as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1   [hostname].[domain].net [hostname] # FQDN


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost localhost.localdomain ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

#
1.1.1.1          [hostname].[domain].net [hostname] [domain].net www.[domain].net
11::11::11::11   [hostname].[domain].net [hostname] [domain].net www.[domain].net
```

The **FQDN** on the second line is required by my VPS provider to later setup rDNS and DKIM.

Here's my */etc/postfix/main.cf*:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname].[domain].net/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[hostname].[domain].net/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
#smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# Authentication
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

# Restrictions
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        defer_unauth_destination


myhostname = [hostname].[domain].net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = [domain].net
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all


# Even more Restrictions and MTA params
disable_vrfy_command = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
#smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
#smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
#smtpd_hard_error_limit = 1
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
maximal_backoff_time = 3h

# Reply Rejection Codes
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
```

Is the **relay access problem** maybe related to the mail server domain being *[hostname].[domain].net*, but the user email address `info@[domain].net`?

Virtual users - currently only `info` - are setup in the MySQL database, which stores their username, encrypted password, and mail storage path. I haven't setup any aliases.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Postfix has to fish the **virtual mailbox domains**, **virtual mailbox maps**, and **virtual aliases** information from different tables from within a **MySQL database** (in my case), I needed to create and provide a configuration file for each one.

Changes made to */etc/postfix/main.cf*:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost

# ...

# Handling of local devlivery to Dovecot's LMTP, and telling it where to store mail
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

# Virtual domains, users, and aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
        mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

All these config files have the same structure:

```
user = database_user
password = database_user_password
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = database_name
query = MySQL query that gets the relevant information from a specific table
```

Comment: BTW, your "Here's my /etc/postfix/main.cf:" was missing all the MySQL related configuration parameters as well as the MySQL config files. This would have been impossible to solve without this missing information.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`mydestination`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) only has the FQDN of your server (`$myhostname`), but not your domain. Try adding `$mydomain`, e.g.,

```
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

For [`virtual_alias_domains`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains), you must specify **every** user in [`virtual_alias_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_maps), and for [`virtual_mailbox_domains`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_domains)
in [`virtual_mailbox_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps); not just the `info@exmple.com`.

Also, all your restrictions are missing the final `permit`.

From [postconf(5) `smtpd_client_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions):

> **permit**
>
> Permit the request. This restriction is useful at the end of a restriction list, to make the default policy explicit.

E.g.,

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unlisted_recipient,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    permit
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't help! Same result - `relay access denied` - after adding the `permit`s and restarting Postfix.

Comment: I've added a couple more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. Your suggestion about the virtual_mailbox_domains and _maps made me realize what I forgot!
Adding `$mydomain` to `mydestination` was discouraged by Dovecot so I removed it.